# Why my project always download appcompat v7 version 23 when i setting in gradle is appcompat v7 version 22?

Tags: android, gradle, libgdx, android-support-library, android-appcompat

i use libgdx to make a game ,import BaseGameUltis into my project and setting in gradle file is :

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.+"
```

But in folder BaseGameUtils\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7 always version 23.0.0 and i get this error because i can't complie with android version 23, BaseGameUltis is not compatible with android ver 23:

```
BaseGameUtils\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.0.0\res\values-v23\values-v23.xml
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
```

This is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.+"
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
```

What do i do wrong? Thank for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to compile with api 23.**
Change in your `build.gradle` this line:

```
 compileSdkVersion 23
```

Since you are using the

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

you are using the the latest version **8.4.0** which has a dependency with support **libraries v23**.
It is the reason because gradle uses the v23 instead of v22.

In general it is a good practice **avoiding the use of +** in your `build.gradle` files because in this way you don't know which version you are using of your dependencies and you will not able to reproduce your code in the future.

**Also don't use different version of the support libraries.** In your case your trying to use com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22 and com.android.support:support-v4:20.

Finally, use `gradle myModule:dependencies` to check the full list of your module.

Comment: Thank for help. I try use android.gms:play-services 7.5 and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Fix your dependency to a `static version` by deleting the **plus symbol (+)** in the end of declaration like `compile`"com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.x"`

For more information check it [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html) in gradle documentation